# How to get the value of variable between 2 JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value from one file to another file but could not.

in my first file I have:

```
  theVar = "testing123";
  module.exports = theVar;
```

in my second file that i need to use the variable from the first file:

```
   const TheVar = require('../server.js');
   var test = TheVar;
   console.log(test);
```

I am not getting any errors and I am not getting any message either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first file your variable is not initialized, so you don't export anything. First initialize the variable with "let" or "const" and you will be fine.

```
const \ let theVar = "testing123";
module.exports = theVar;
```